# Why can't I decode('utf-16') success in Python3 (even work in Py2)?

Tags: python-3.x, decode, utf-16

In Py2:

```
(chr(145) + chr(78)).decode('utf-16')
```

I got `u'\u4e91'`:

But in Py3:

```
(chr(145) + chr(78)).encode('utf-8').decode('utf-16')
```

I got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode byte 0x4e in position 2: truncated data
```

Sometimes, they work in a same way, such as `(chr(93) + chr(78))`, but sometimes not.

Why? And how can I do this right in Py3?

Comment: Try building it up using a `btyearray`, i.e., `bytearray((145, 78)).decode('utf-16')`. This should work in py2 and py3.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `latin1` if you want to encode any byte tranparently:

```
(chr(145) + chr(78)).encode('latin1').decode('utf-16')

#'云'
```

`chr(145)` gets encoded with 2 bytes in utf8 (as with all values above 127):

```
chr(145).encode('utf8')
# b'\xc2\x91'
```

while it is what you wanted with latin1:

```
chr(145).encode('latin1')
# b'\x91'
```